# Upgrading to Signalr 2.0.0 get error 404

Tags: signalr

I have upgraded my Web API server to the new MVC5 and Signalr 2.0 and also created the startup file with the hub mapping, my client isnt deployed from the same server but from different so i am not using generated proxies. after the upgrade on the negotiation i am getting 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that `appSettings` in `web.config` had this line:

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
```

Setting that to `true` fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable cross-domain connections on your hub? You can add the following to your Configuration method:

app.UseCors();

Also, are you using IIS 7 or 7.5? You'll need to add a patch that enables extensionless URLs:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368